# Apache POI : Why exception on copy of same excel file?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Hi I am working with `xyz.xlsx` files, I want to read the cotents. I have one original sheet `'xyz.xlsx'` on which my application is able to get the data, but when I create a copy of above excel using google sheets `'xyzcopy.xlsx'` application throws

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

I am not able to figure out the problem.

```
07-08 14:01:52.372 8005-7378/com.myapp W/System.err: org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-08 14:01:52.372 8005-7378/com.myapp W/System.err:     at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:62)
07-08 14:01:52.372 8005-7378/com.myapp W/System.err:     at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:426)
07-08 14:01:52.372 8005-7378/com.myapp W/System.err:     at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:431)
07-08 14:01:52.372 8005-7378/com.myapp W/System.err:     at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:155)
07-08 14:01:52.372 8005-7378/com.myapp W/System.err:     at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:221)
07-08 14:01:52.372 8005-7378/com.myapp W/System.err:     at com.myapp.activities_dealer.UploadExcelCustomerActivity$MyExcelTask.run(UploadExcelCustomerActivity.java:350)
07-08 14:01:52.372 8005-7378/com.myapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-08 14:01:52.372 8005-7378/com.myapp W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-08 14:01:52.372 8005-7378/com.myapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-08 14:01:52.372 8005-7378/com.myapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
07-08 14:01:52.372 8005-7378/com.myapp W/System.err:     at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:60)
07-08 14:01:52.372 8005-7378/com.myapp W/System.err:    ... 6 more
07-08 14:01:52.372 8005-7378/com.myapp W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlComplexContentImpl cannot be cast to org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.CTDrawing
07-08 14:01:52.372 8005-7378/com.myapp W/System.err:     at org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.CTDrawing$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
07-08 14:01:52.372 8005-7378/com.myapp W/System.err:     at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing.<init>(XSSFDrawing.java:84)
07-08 14:01:52.372 8005-7378/com.myapp W/System.err:    ... 9 more
```

By two ways I created my copies of the given file using google sheets,

```
1] clicking File->Make a copy,
2] Ctrl + a & then Ctrl + v in a new sheet,
```

And downloaded the resultant files using :

```
File->Download as..-> Microsoft Excel .xlsx
```

Files created by above two methods throws exception. Meanwhile the original one keeps working without any problem.

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Secondarily, what do you mean "when I create a copy of above excel using google sheets"? What exactly happens?

Comment: xlsx basically is a zip file containing XML files. So you could do a compare. Trying out ever smaller sheets

Comment: Hello @Joop Eggen, ifly, & Jens I just figured it out that when I edit using google sheet above exception appears but when I do editing using microsoft live excel it works even after editing & copying

Comment: What's the cause of the exception? We need the full stacktrace!

Comment: @Gagravarr I have updated the question

Comment: Try swapping out `poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14` for the bigger `ooxml-schemas-1.3` ?